# How to make load balancing work from the pfSense box itself?

Tags: freebsd, routing, load-balancing, pfsense

pdSense is a special distro of FreeBSD for routing. It supports limited multi WAN load balancing, i.e. it is possible to configure pfSense so that each next request will connect via different WAN interface (in round robin manner).

But I found, that load balancing does not work if ran from pfSense box itself.

For example, if I query

```
curl somesite.com
```

then the site sees that requests are coming from default gateway only.

Simultaneously, if I do the same command from any computer in the LAN, the requests are coming from different gateways, i.e. load balancing is working.

How to do so that load balancing work from pfSense too?

And if it is impossible, then what is the reason for that?

Comment: From the doc they say: _Policy routing traffic from the firewall itself is not currently possible, and as such, load balancing is not possible. Failover can be achieved in many cases by using default gateway switching under System > Advanced on the Miscellaneous tab._

Comment: Okay, then the question is why? What is the principal difference between accessing Inet from router OS itself or from LAN computer's OS?

Comment: I think that it is because of some security of pfSense itself that act as router and firewall, rather than the other OS of the LAN that are just tools. I would like to install another pfSense in the same LAN and test to confirm.

Comment: Then if yes, create another one on OpenBSD for example and try to set it  as clause as possible to pfSense to determine if it comes from a software or a setting.

Comment: Without that type of experimentation, I think that just pfSense maintainer knows from where it comes.